Import powerpoint with hyperlinks into LaTeX: possible?
I have a lot of powerpoints, with hyperlinks in them. I would like to import those into a LaTeX document, without loosing the hyperlink capacities in the powerpoints.
I tried saving the powerpoints as pdf, and then import those using pdfpages: it works as expected, but I loose all the hyperlink functionality. I know there is something like pax (or newpax and maybe other similar alternatives?), but I don't seem to be able to get pax up and running on windows.
Is there some solution/workaround to import powerpoints into LaTeX, that is not too complicated?
Or is there a not too complicated tutorial on how to make (new-)pax operational on windows?
Thanks
Stef

I am on windows and I can use newpax there. So I suggest that you try it (the documentation is not so long and it contains examples) and ask a specific question with a complete example if something doesn't work.

Oke, I tried (and succeeded finally) to do that. It took me quite some time (many hours), but I have to admit that I'm far from familiar with LaTeX (I use LyX and windows, does it show that I'm more of a WYSIWYG-person? ;-).
I'm still having problems now with the pdf files created from within powerpoint. The .newpax files for those pdf don't seem to work, while I can make the example in the newpax-documentation operational.

well as I wrote: if something doesn't work, I need a concrete example (including a powerpoint pdf, I don't have powerpoint) so that I can try to reproduce the problem.  At best open then an issue at the github.  And no, a lyx file is not acceptable. It must be a normal, complete latex file.

Oke, thanks. Now I notice that if I work outside LyX, using Miktex all the time, everything works fine, both the pdfs that are distibuted with newpax as the ones I created from powerpoint. But when I try to do this from within LyX, only the pdfs from newpax keep the hyperlinks (albeit partially: not all the links in the output do work). The links in the pdfs from powerpoint don't work at all.
So this narrows down to a LyX problem, I think. I'll check with a LyX forum for this one. Thanks for your time.

That sounds as if newpax in lyx is outdated. Are you using the same TeX system in lyx?

As far as I can tell, yes (MiKTeX). I contacted the LyX-developers, and they suspect it has something to do with LyX using a tmp directory for
processing the files and mangling file names to have unique naming,
while the newpax files (which also aren't copied to the tmp) link to
files in the local working directory and to unmangled names.

Well tmp folders could do harm but that would affect all pdf and so doesn't explain why some work and other not.
